# How can I make Clojure program hotswap on edit

Tags: clojure

I have watched [this exciting video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0GzzFeS5cMc). Looks very promising tool to edit program at runtime, but when I tried to edit for example [this program](https://gist.github.com/spacemanaki/1093917) after started it changes nothing. How to achieve such a functionality.
It there any library necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for certain environments there are are ready to use plugins and libraries which do the reloading for you. Like [figwheel](https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel) for web and [test-refresh](https://github.com/jakemcc/lein-test-refresh) for tests / simple scripts and others.

If you have some special environment, where a ready to use solution does not fit, you could build something on you're own. For example by running `(use my-namespace :reload-all)` periodically / when a file changes.

A abstract example for 'poor mans' reload implementation:

```
(defn game-loop [] 
   (while true 
         ; If a file changes, we want to reload that code
         (when (any-file-changed?)
              (use 'my-game.main :reload-all)
         )
         (my-game.main/tick)  ; Call the game tick every frame
    )
)
```